# How to access components created under nested modules via direct url path in browser

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router

How can I access components created under nested modules via direct url path in browser.

```
app module
    -- device module
        -- module-building module
            -- BuildingComponent
```

'module-building' module is created under device module which is again under app module.

I want to access BuildingComponent of 'module-building' module directly through url in browser.

In device-routing.module.ts I have done like this,

```
{
     path: 'building', loadChildren: () => import(`./module-building/module-building.module`).then(m => m.ModuleBuildingModule)
}
```

In module-building-routing.module.ts I have done like

```
{
    path: 'building3', component: BuildingComponent
}
```

When I try to access the BuildingComponent with below url it is not loading.

```
http://localhost:4200/building/building3
```

What am I missing? I am new to Angular.

Comment: Do you have anything in the browser console? Also, what happens instead of the desired page loading?

Comment: No browser is showing nothing rather than white blank screen. In console,----- core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'building/building3'

Comment: Then this seems like that the routing files are not picked up by the router. What happens if you open `http://localhost:4200/building`?

Comment: When I open http://localhost:4200/building it is opening http://localhost:4200/building/signin automatically and the sign in page comes up...
I have some other module login.module (under app module, parallel to device module) which has its routing ts file having
 {
        path:' ', redirectTo: 'signin', pathMatch:'full'
    }
So it is going to the other component of other module

Comment: I don't have any more particular ideas. Can you maybe post the whole routing files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you Imported ModuleBuildingRouting in ModuleBuildingModule. (file: module-building.module.ts)

```
 @NgModule({
  declarations: [BuildingComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ModuleBuildingRouting, //<-- here   
  ]
})
export class ModuleBuildingModule { }
```

Comment: Yes, I added it now and it resolved the issue. Thanks for the suggestion.